# i have java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, for-loop

In a Prediction Game, two or more players attempt to predict the score of a series of upcoming sporting competitions. Each player's predictions are then evaluated based on the sum of the categories listed below. These descriptions use the following variables:

S1: Actual score earned by team 1.

S2: Actual score earned by team 2.

P1: A player's predicted score for team 1.

P2: A player's predicted score for team 2.

but I have exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
public void game() {
    int s1, s2, p1, p2, winner, team1, team2, pointSpread, total = 0;

    int testCase = scan.nextInt();

    for (int k = 0; k < testCase; k++) {

        int p = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();

        int[]result = new int[p];
        String[]pName = new String[p];

        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            pName[i] = scan.next();

            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                p1 = scan.nextInt();
                p2 = scan.nextInt();
                s1 = 20;
                s2 = 13;

                if (s1 > s2 && p1 > p2) {
                    winner = 10;
                }
                if (s1 < s2 && p1 < p2) {
                    winner = 10;
                } else {
                    winner = 0;
                }

                team1 = 5 - Math.abs(s1 - p1);
                team2 = 5 - Math.abs(s2 - p2);
                pointSpread = 5 - Math.abs(p1 - p2)-(s1 - s2);

                total += winner + team1 + team2 + pointSpread;
                result[i] = total;
            }
        }

        //compare players scores
        int max = result[0], playerNo = 0;
        for (int m = 1; m <= p; m++)//this line error
            if (max < result[m]) {
                max = result[m];
                playerNo = m;
            }

        System.out.println(pName[playerNo]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Index Out of Bounds Exception (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549869/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception-java)

Answer (score 2):

Change the error line to `for(int m=1; m<p;m++)`

Comment: @Arc676 Please comment only after checking the facts. Index 0 is already handled by the user outside the loop.

Comment: Sorry. The comment was outside the default size of the code snipped and it looked like the code ended there (before the loop). My bad.