# Array Index out of Bound Merge Sort

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I am working on a Merge Sort algorithm but I am having issues getting this pseudo code working properly. I am getting an array out of bounds error on line 100 "           s[k] = u[i];"

I am not sure why it is wrong. It is based off the pseduo code. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much apreciated.

Here is the algorithm:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class MergeSortAnalysis {
private static int[] aux;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * Merge Sort CALL
     */
    System.out.println("_____________________\nMerge Sort\n");
    //random dta
    int data[] =new int[10];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<=9;i++) 
    {
        data[i] = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Data Input: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    printArray(data);

    System.out.println("Sorted: ");
    MergeSort(10,data);




    /**
     * Merge Sort 2 CALL
     */
    System.out.println("_____________________\nMerge Sort 2\n");
    //random input
    int input[] =new int[10];
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    System.out.println("Input Before Sort: ");
    for (int i=0; i<=9;i++) 
    {
        input[i] = rand1.nextInt(50) + 1;

    }
    printArray(input);

    MergeSortAnalysis.sort(input);
    System.out.println("After Sort: ");
    printArray(input);


}
/**
 * Print Array
 * 
 */
public static void printArray(int p[]) {
    System.out.println("Output");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));


}




/**
 * Merge Sort Code - does not work
 * 
 * 
 */
public static void MergeSort(int n,int s[]) {
    int h=n/2;
    int m=n-h;
     int[] u = new int[h];
     int[] j = new int[m];
     if(n>1)
     {
      for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
      {
       u[i] = s[i];
      }
      for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
      {
       j[i] = s[h+i];
      }
      MergeSort(h,u);
      MergeSort(m,j);
      merge(h,m,u,j,s);
     }

}

public static void merge(int h, int m, int u[], int v[],int s[]) {
     int i, j, k;
     i=j=k=0;
     while(i<h && j<m) 
     {  
      if(u[i]<v[j])
      {
       s[k] = u[i];
      }
      else
      {
       s[k]=v[j];
       j++;   
      }
      k++;
     }  
     if(i>=h)
     {
      for(int a=j; a<m; a++)
      {
       s[k] = v[a];
       k++;
      }
     }else
     {
      for( int a=i; a<h;a++)
      {
       s[k] = u[a];
       k++;
      } 
     }


    printArray(s);

}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: have you refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549869/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception-java

Comment: I am familiar with what the error means.- calling for an index out of bound of the set length of the array. But going off the pseudo code I am lost as to why this does not work. This is the 3rd time writing this portion.

Comment: If you think that you can copy psuedo-code and have it work exactly like code, you are not thinking correctly. You need to think about how it should be put in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In merge(), after

```
   s[k] = u[i];
```

the code is missing

```
   i++;
```

There may be other issues, but this seems to be the main one.